# Native Entity Framework Transactions Behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I read some articles, like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) one, where they say:

> In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute
>   SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the
>   framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction
>   lasts only long enough to execute the operation and then completes.
>   When you execute another such operation a new transaction is started.

But I can't understand from this description how does EF behaves when I have multiple changes to be executed. Does it wrap all the `insert`, `update` or `delete` into one `transaction`, or each one of them get it's own `transaction`? The term "*that operation*" in the text can be both the whole `SaveChanges()` operation or the individual `insert`, `update` or `delete`.

A practical example of my question is:

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.MyClass1.Add(myObject1);
    var myObject2 = context.MyClass2.Single();
    myObject2.Value1 = 10;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would like that if there are any errors setting `myObject2.Value1`  to `10`, the whole operation is canceled, so `myObject1` isn't added to the DB as well and vice versa.

Comment: both add and update actions are wrapped into a transaction, which is called upon calling SaveChanges(). your call to Single() will be another transaction of course, but usually all changes to the context will be reflected in one transaction, namely at SaveChanges().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it wrap all the insert, update or delete into one transaction, or each one of them get it's own transaction?

For the time you instantiate your context until you reach the SaveChanges() method, all operations insert, update and update are executed in a single transaction hence as an atomic operation to the database server. If one of your operation failed all of the operations that are executed in success before reaching the failed one are rollback. But your entites will still have their modifications you have done on them. Only the database server will reject the changes.

> The term "that operation" in the text can be both the whole SaveChanges() operation or the individual insert, update or delete.

It represents the hole `SaveChanges` as an ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) operation.

> I would like that if there are any errors setting myObject2.Value1 to 10, the whole operation is canceled, so myObject1 isn't added to the DB as well and vice versa.

Your object modifications aren't added to the database but object's state in your application is not lost. The value 10 will still be there as a value of `Value1` if you check the value of this property.

Comment: SaveChanges is transactional but the rest is not. That's an important difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest"?

Comment: Good question, @mFeinstein. What do he mean by "the rest"?